# DataWeave Transformation remove duplicates based on value

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have a payload that is an array of objects. I want to remove duplicate objects with the same id however if the returnComment is `1`, that should be kept over the one being `2`. Basically `1` has higher priority over `2` in deciding which object to keep. How would one do it based on this condition?

Payload:

```
[
    {
      "id": "1676431",
      "returnComment": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "1676431",
      "returnComment": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "1676431",
      "returnComment": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "3566367",
      "returnComment": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "7676559",
      "returnComment": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "7676559",
      "returnComment": 1
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {
      "id": "1676431",
      "returnComment": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "3566367",
      "returnComment": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "7676559",
      "returnComment": 1
    },
]
```

Current Code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---

arr distinctBy $.requestId
```

Comment: What is `arr` in your script?

Comment: arr is just the payload

Comment: Then just use payload. It should be easy for people to reproduce what you are trying to do. Using a non existent variable means that the script as is doesn't work. People may waste effort into that instead of your actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can first orderBy returnComment so all 1's will come first followed by 2's then if you order by id 1's will be picked as first priority over 2 and final ordering is to sort based on id's.

DataWeave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(((payload orderBy $.returnComment) distinctBy $.id) orderBy $.id)
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1676431",
    "returnComment": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "3566367",
    "returnComment": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "7676559",
    "returnComment": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: That is a great idea! Thank you so much